# Why do pointers point to memory and not a value?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm currently learning about pointers in my C++ Algorithms class and while I understand the material, I don't understand why C++ makes pointers point to a memory slot and not to just a certain value that you could change later.

It would seem like you would want to be able to dynamically create a new variable in the very memory slot your pointer is taking up.

Is it because the Operating System creates all dynamic variables on the Heap and we need a way to find them because our pointer is made when the program loads?

If that is it then I totally understand that, but if that's not it then it seems like a complete waste of memory space and an extra process our programs have to go through to access the destination value of the pointer.

Comment: "A certain value that you could change later"? You mean like a variable in memory?

Comment: Play with assembly for a few days and it will make a lot more sense. I knew how to use pointers before asm, but did not really understand the why. Your program is also going to be loaded into memory, and hard coding all the memory locations takes space too. Increasing a pointer may be shorter than storing the whole address of the next memory location. Space this small is not normally the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is actually saved in the case where you have large objects (by large I mean greater than 4 or 8 bytes, i.e. `sizeof(void *)`). Instead of paying for expensive copy and overwrite operations you just pass a pointer - which is smaller than the object - and assign it that way.

Dynamic allocation is for allocation that you can't predict ahead of time, like variable-sized arrays and different state objects that you may or may not need depending on the conditions. You really don't waste memory at all. If you passed them by value you would waste more time and more memory.

The pointer itself is a memory address but what it points to is a value in memory. This also applies to something like `int **` because it points to a pointer value in memory.

The operating system doesn't create them dynamically, you do. You tell the program to allocate a new object or a certain sized memory block and the OS just gives it to you.

You can always reuse pointers. For instance, if I allocate space for a 100-byte array I can always reuse that as long as I keep a pointer to it, so long as I don't free it until I'm done with that space (you're actually encouraged to do so).

Comment: This is crazy, but I actually understand this.  Thank you.

Comment: You can have variable-length arrays without dynamic allocation (see `alloca` and C99 VLAs).

Comment: @FredOverflow I was trying to give examples and that was one of the easiest I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

Your question would be best illustrated with code samples and A/B contrasts.  (It's rather abstract as stated, and hard to know what you might mean.)

C++ offers you the choice to allocate things on "the stack" or "dynamically":

```
/* foo is an integer on "the stack" */
int foo = 1;

/* bar is a pointer on "the stack", *bar is an integer on "the heap" */
int* bar = new int (1);
```

Both `bar` and `&foo` point to integers whose value is `1`.  It's true to say that `bar` consumes memory not just for that integer, but also for a stack variable that tracks the pointer to it.

The issue is that once a function or block scope is over, the variables declared on the stack vanish.  Yet sometimes you would like to be talking about the object or quantity afterward, and manage its lifetime explicitly.  In these cases this "unnecessary" descriptive term that is a pointer becomes necessary.

All things being equal you should not use dynamic allocation.  C++ programmers often try to encourage C programmers to rethink their code to not need it.  However, this "additional memory to store a pointer" *is the least of your concerns* in terms of why to avoid the practice.  It's mostly about the dangling responsibility of whose job it is to eventually do the `delete`...

Comment: So variables on the stack vanish and variables on the heap remain?  If you declare your pointer in a function how do you go about finding it after the function has gone out of scope?  Do you have a global point to it?

Comment: @JeramyRR Even in garbage collected languages you have to make the result of a "new object" be passed back through a return value, global, or "by reference" parameter.  The only difference is that in C++ if you `new` something but then never return it to anyone, there's no possible chain of responsibility to do the `delete`...(which is why `shared_ptr` and other "smart pointers" are cool).  But you need to be careful not to return the addresses of *stack-allocated* variables from a function to its caller...those pointers will be no good after the return!  :-/

Comment: If I use delete on lets say *deleteMe then it will only delete the memeory that holds the address of another variable right?  It won't actually delete the variable it's pointing to will it?

Comment: In my example, `delete bar` frees the integer-sized memory block holding the value `1`.  After that point, you should not dereference the pointer using `*` to try and get the integer.  But since the integer pointer `bar` is still on the stack, it can be re-used as the target of an assignment (or another allocation).  Note that it is possible to make pointers to pointers...so you could write `int** frotz = new int* (new int (1));`.  In such a case if you said `delete frotz` it would delete an integer pointer, but not the int itself (you'd have to save the pointer elsewhere to avoid leaking).

Answer (score 1):

To add to other good answers a little, I think that understanding how computers work can also be helpful in understanding pointers and why we need them. In my own words - every logical operation in computer is done by the CPU (in the most simple case, of course). CPU itself have extremely little memory. For example, 32-bit [i386](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) CPU has 8 [registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) it can operate on, where each register can hold only 4 bytes of data (32-bit). So 32 bytes is all that can fit into CPU. The rest of the data is stored in other [circuits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_circuit) like [CPU cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache), [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) etc. So when you want CPU to do something, you have to ask it to load data from external circuits, and that's where you need "to point" CPU to what exactly you want it to load, and you have to give it an "address" of memory. And C pointers are exactly those addresses, providing you with the lowest level of addressing memory locations in such a high-level languages.

Now, everything in your program is placed somewhere in memory (even CPUs registers are technically memory, but they are addressed differently). Be that some value on stack, or dynamically allocated region of memory (stack is also dynamically allocated, after all), and you can always refer to those objects by their addresses in memory. A pointer itself is a value (4 bytes on i386 or 8 on amd64) that holds address to something (and yes, you can point to that value, too, creating a pointer to a pointer). So pointers are everywhere, even if you don't see them. Just for example, when you copy some large "object", memory to hold a copy of that object have to be allocated, and then CPU have to be instructed to copy bytes from a source memory region into a destination memory region, byte by byte, addressing those bytes "trough pointers" (i.e. [here](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Assembler/comp.lang.asm.x86/2006-02/msg00123.html) is how actual CPU instructions might look like in assembler).

Even in extremely high-level languages like Java, pointers are everywhere. They are just hidden from developers.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That does help.  I'm also taking CISS 360 Assembly Language right now, but the semester just started so we haven't gotten to all that yet.

Answer (score 0):

> why C++ makes pointers point to a memory slot and not to just a
>   certain value that you could change later.

If so why do you need pointers? Also note that pointers is a two-in-one offer, while pointing to a memory location, you can also access the value at the pointed memory, say,

```
int a;
int *b;
b=&a;
```

---

```
 b >> memmory location
*b >> value
```

and here is a good tutorial for you : [Pointers and
Memory](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but I suspect that you're making some implicit assumptions about pointers that aren't true.

You question why C++ "makes pointers point to a memory slot and not to just a certain value that you could change later". But a slot in memory is in fact the only valid place to store a value! It's a reasonable approximation to say that all data in your entire program is stored in a huge group of slots. It's like an enormous array.

Memory and values are very tightly interwoven. You can't have one without the other, and there is no other way to store things (except, maybe, storing to disk - and yes, there are registers too, but C/C++ abstracts those away).

I also want to address how you say "It would seem like you would want to be able to dynamically create a new variable in the very memory slot your pointer is taking up."

The spot that the pointer is taking up is filled with the address of where the pointer's value is (where it "points to"). If you were to create a new variable in that slot, you would lose all knowledge of where the pointer points to! So it's important that we keep that memory slot with the value we need.

"Is it because the Operating System creates all dynamic variables on the Heap and we need a way to find them because our pointer is made when the program loads?"

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "dynamic variable", but no, not all pointers are stored on the heap. Simple example:

```
int a = 5;
int *b = &a;
```

Notice that b is a pointer that points to a, but both `a` and `b` are on the stack, not the heap.

If by dynamic you mean "created with `new`", then yes, it is fair to say that all things created with new are created on the heap.

Another important note: The Operating System does not (generally) manage memory allocation. The most it will do is give you a big chunk of heap memory to do whatever you want with. If you're interested, check into the C routine called `malloc`, which is a way to allocate memory on the heap, much like `new`. There is really not a lot of magic behind it.